# Django Wiki - URL Include Circular Reference Error

Tags: python, django, wiki

I have installed ([Django Wiki](https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki)) via pip on Windows 10 Professional. The installed python version is 3.6.2. I am currently receiving the following error during server startup when running `manage.py runserver`:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001BD23F6DE1A>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 360, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 347, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 82, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 17, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 27, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 27, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 255, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "Documents\Projects\Documentation\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 415, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'wiki.urls' from 'Documents\\Projects\\Documentation\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\wiki\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`'
```

Current packages installed are:

```
bleach==1.5.0
Django==1.11.14
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-mptt==0.8.7
django-nyt==1.0
django-sekizai==0.10.0
html5lib==0.9999999
Markdown==2.6.11
Pillow==5.2.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
pytz==2018.5
six==1.11.0
sorl-thumbnail==12.4.1
wiki==0.3.1
```

In settings.py I have configured the following items:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.sites.apps.SitesConfig',
        'django.contrib.humanize.apps.HumanizeConfig',
        'django_nyt.apps.DjangoNytConfig',
        'mptt',
        'sekizai',
        'sorl.thumbnail',
        'wiki.apps.WikiConfig',
        'wiki.plugins.attachments.apps.AttachmentsConfig',
        'wiki.plugins.notifications.apps.NotificationsConfig',
        'wiki.plugins.images.apps.ImagesConfig',
        'wiki.plugins.macros.apps.MacrosConfig',
    ]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WIKI_ACCOUNT_HANDLING = True
WIKI_ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_ALLOWED = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('wiki:get', kwargs={'path': ''})
```

In urls.py I have included the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^notifications/', include('django_nyt.urls')),
    url(r'', include('wiki.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Maybe Wiki is not compatible with Django `1.11.14`?, they only say `1.11`